# Process.Start launch process in Visual Studio but not in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, process, process.start

I can launch a process when I run my web application with Visual Studio.
But when I publish my application on IIS and try to launch the process, a message tells me that the "Access is denied".

Here is my code :

`Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();`

`p.StartInfo.FileName = path;`

`p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;`

`p.Start();`

Have you an idea to solve the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your website launching the process? Chances are there's a better way to resolve the setup.

Comment: The Account of the AppPool must have the rights to execute the .exe.

Comment: Website is a kind of watchdog. Then how to set the rights to execute the .exe ? Thanks.